# i see masqeraded ping from ipsec tunnel on OpenVZ vps wan interface, but it did not going out

Tags: networking, ping, tunnel, openvz

I have fully working ipsec tunnel:

```
Windows7_lan_mashine -> VPS_IPSEC (OpenVZ virtual machine)
```

i can ping VPS_IPSEC from Win7, and can ping Win7 from VPS_IPSEC

Now i try ping my second  internet mashine VPS_TEST  from Win7  through  ipsec tunnel.

On VPS_IPSEC i have:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 84 bytes)         
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      venet0  192.168.88.0/24      0.0.0.0/0            policy match dir out pol ipsec
8   480 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      venet0  192.168.88.0/24      0.0.0.0/0
```

By tcpdump  -nni venet0 icmp  i see on my outgoing venet0

```
IP 192.168.88.251 > 194.67.209.193: ICMP echo request, id 54790, seq 1821, length 64
IP 185.69.52.31 > 194.67.209.193: ICMP echo request, id 54790, seq 1821, length 64
IP 192.168.88.251 > 194.67.209.193: ICMP echo request, id 54790, seq 1822, length 64
IP 185.69.52.31 > 194.67.209.193: ICMP echo request, id 54790, seq 1822, length 64
```

i.e i see pings on outgoing interface, but it have no replay, and no incoming icmp traffic on VPS_TEST(i see it by tcpdump).
So all ping traffic stay on VPS_IPSEC.

What is going on??

I can give root access to VPS_IPSEC if necessary

Answer (score -1):

This problem related  with OpenVz vps limitations. Running same ipsec tunnel on KVM vps solve problem.